# Javascript script loading order - function undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, velocity.js

I am working within a not so nice template which has forced me to load some scripts in with JS as I can not control there order. I am trying to load a library but when I attempt to call it, I get an undefined error.

```
$.getScript( "js/velocity.min.js").done(function(){
    $('body').velocity({ width: 200})
});
```

Get error: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).velocity is not a function

How can this be? I just loaded you!

[image]

Ok there was a conflict with another script which has to be loaded, to fix this I wrapper the velocity code in a closure and set 'define' to null within it.

```
(function($){
    var define = null;
    //then velocity code is here
})(jQuery)
```

Comment: Are you sure that the script has been successfully loaded?

Comment: Hey, yeah I can see it in the network tab

Comment: It's most probabaly because it won't able to get velocity.min.js

Comment: check your js file is fine or not some times corrupted js files also creates problem

Comment: @CodeWithCoffee no because otherwise success callback would't be fired

Comment: as i saw from their website, they mostly call it as `$.Velocity`, so, maybe check the syntax here: http://julian.com/research/velocity/#utilityFunction

Comment: @Icepickle That's the documentation for the utility function. It's `$().velocity()` everywhere else.

Comment: @Icepickle jQuery's selectors return a jQuery object, so if `$.velocity()` works then I believe `$('elem').velocity()` should also work.

Comment: To check jQuery conflicts, try changing `$('body').velocity({ width: 200})` by `jQuery('body').velocity({ width: 200})`, but I don' think the problem is there. If you can check it we can discard it.

Comment: Tried with jQuery, unfortunately its the same error

Comment: I imagined. Let's try to load the script from other site, like `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.2.2/velocity.min.js`

Comment: Can you do `$('body').velocity({..})` later via DevTools? Or it still throws?

Comment: Please check this codepen, they seem to use `jquery.velocity.js` rather than velocity.min.js: http://codepen.io/julianshapiro/pen/wmtEH

Comment: Tried from CDN, loads in but error remains, running the code in dev tools also throws the same error.

Comment: Just curiosity (and it should be the same), but can you change your function to `$.getScript('js/velocity.min.js', function(){ $('body').velocity({ width: 200}); })`?

Comment: Unfortunately the same. I have attempted to load in another library under the same method and it works - it seems to be exclusive to velocity - may be the versions have a conflict

Comment: What libraries are you loading? Do you have only a jQuery version?

Comment: Libraries are jquery-1.7.2 and Velocity-1.2.2

Comment: Can you try with an updated version of jQuery? Like ~2.1.3

Comment: When I use this link (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/julianshapiro/velocity/master/velocity.min.js), I get this error about MIME Types: *"...because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled"*, followed by this error: *"Uncaught TypeError: $(...).velocity is not a function"*... But when I use this link (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.2.2/velocity.min.js), it does work for me without any errors: **[SEE WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/u7cgmLch/)**

Comment: There seems to be a conflict between velocity and requirejs which is also being loaded in, removing this fixes the problem, but that is not an option

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://julian.com/research/velocity/ (search the page for "requirejs")

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to be loading Zepto/jQuery before Velocity.js

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/zepto.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/velocity.min.js"></script>
```